# Sending most correct mimetype

Tags: content-type, mime-types

I have a list of extension to mimetype in a INI file. However some extensions have multiple mimetypes, for example;

`midi[] = "application/x-midi"`
`midi[] = "audio/midi"`
`midi[] = "audio/x-mid"`
`midi[] = "audio/x-midi"`
`midi[] = "music/crescendo"`
`midi[] = "x-music/x-midi"`

6 (possible) mimetypes for 1 extension. Whats common practice to determine the correct mimetype? (e.g. i need to set a HTTP content-type header).

I know its not ideal; determining mimetypes based on extension.. but i need consistent (cross-server) results (e.g. fileinfo extension in PHP is making terrible guesses*).

* Some fileinfo results for example;

- js - text/plain
- css - text/c-h

Comment: Well im programming in PHP, but i can imagine the same issue pops up in other languages.

Also its not just only "as a value of content-type", but optional other purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i final came up with is the following;

First i use "FileInfo" for 100% (known) matches (e.g. gif, jpeg, png) because i do want to rely on "fingerprint" detection for certain files.

If above fails, i fallback on a "extension 2 mimetype" map; based on docs/conf/mime.types (I filtered all common used files; e.g. image, audio, video, web, text)

If still no match found, i use "FileInfo" again; allowing any result.

At this point, if the mimetype is still not set i return "application/octet-stream" hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day the best you have is the file extension.

For definite list, locate this in the apache source tree:
docs/conf/mime.types

Comment: I already figured that out ;-) The point is i have multiple possible mimetypes to choose from... and im not sure which one to pick.

Edit;
Hm.. "definite list" as in 1 extenstion pointed to 1 mimetype?

Comment: No, you can have multiple extensions going to 1 mimetype. For example exe, dll, com, bat and msi map to application/x-msdownload I wish I could paste the list here but its like well over 1000 entries!

Comment: I looked at the list.. and its indeed definite (e.g. 1 mimetype per extension.. however youre right about how they formatted it; multiple extensions mapped to 1 mimetype).. im going to stick with this however, thanks!